# convert json object to specific json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json object `{"yAxis" : { "Batting" : [10, 20, 30, 40] , "Bowling" : [10, 30, 50, 70], "Fielding" : [20, 40, 50, 70] } },`

and want to convert to json array like this

```
[ { "name": "Batting" ,"data": [10,20,30,40]} , { "name": "Bowling" ,"data": [10,30,50,70] },{ "name": "Fielding" ,"data": [20,40,50,70]}]
```

I can create json object for each index but how can i put those to json array?

```
for(var abc in objJSON.yAxis)
{

    seriesValues +=  JSON.stringify({name:abc,data:(objJSON.yAxis)[abc]});
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close:

```
var seriesValues = [];
for (var abc in objJSON.yAxis) {
  seriesValues.push({name: abc, data: objJSON.yAxis[abc]});
}
```

That will make a javascript array.  If you need it as a JSON string then append:

```
var myString = JSON.stringify(seriesValues);
```

Comment: @Mohan in the interest of learning could you please explain why you unaccepted my answer?  Is there a bug in this code?

Answer (score 2):

You can just loop through creating the object, don't worry about `stringify`ing it.

```
var obj = {"yAxis" : { "Batting" : [10, 20, 30, 40] , "Bowling" : [10, 30, 50, 70], "Fielding" : [20, 40, 50, 70] } };

var keys = Object.keys(obj.yAxis),
    narray = [];
keys.forEach(function(v) {
    narray.push({ "name": v, "data": obj.yAxis[v] });
});
```

Then, if you need to stringify it, you can simply do a `JSON.stringify(narray)` later on.

Answer (score 0):

Simply stringify after the array generated all around.

```
var result = [];

for(var name in objJSON.yAxis)
{
    result.push({name: name, data: objJSON.yAxis[name]});
}

return JSON.stringify(result);
```